# Display multiline rows in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I am using ELK stack to process logs containing java exceptions spanning over multiple lines. I am using a table visualization to display exceptions.

But I can only see first line of exceptions in the table. Is there a way to display entire exception stack-trace?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do it before the data gets into Elasticsearch. On Logstash, configure the [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) filter.

Also, you can have a quick read here (http://logz.io/blog/5-logstash-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them/) on how to carefully use the multiline option.